# Error while trying to display a Dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I am getting this weird error and i run out of ideas how to deal with it. So I am trying to create new column using UDF. Everything seems to go okay but when i display the Dataframe i get this error:

```
PythonException: An exception was thrown from a UDF: 'TypeError: Invalid argument, not a string or column: 1.2852000000000001 of type . For column literals, use 'lit', 'array', 'struct' or 'create_map' function.', from , line 2. Full traceback below:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 2, in weightedAv
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/functions.py", line 325, in sum
    return _invoke_function_over_columns("sum", col)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/functions.py", line 95, in _invoke_function_over_columns
    return _invoke_function(name, *(_to_java_column(col) for col in cols))
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/functions.py", line 95, in 
    return _invoke_function(name, *(_to_java_column(col) for col in cols))
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/column.py", line 66, in _to_java_column
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: Invalid argument, not a string or column: 1.2852000000000001 of type . For column literals, use 'lit', 'array', 'struct' or 'create_map' function.
```

Code where I am trying to create new column:

```
df = union_join.withColumn('new', my_udf('Avg Price per Units Eq', 'Sales Value (in 1000)'))
```

UDF function:

```
def weightedAv(val, weig):
    return (sum(weig * val) / sum(weig))
```

NOTE: error pops up while performing `display(df)`

Thanks!

Comment: add the complete error trace

Comment: You're probably just mixing the order of input variables (`1.2852000000000001` is the average, right?)

Comment: @OrenIshShalom Yeah. What i find strange, this operation:

df = union_join.withColumn('new', my_udf('Avg Price per Units Eq', 'Sales Value (in 1000)'))  - finishes with no problem at all

Comment: Is the udf correctly registered with types? Can you add your code please? Also what happens if you run a df.show()? Does this work?